# C++ non-modified bool array changing (OS X)

Tags: c++

I don't quite understand what is going on here. This is very simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using std::endl;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::ostringstream;

template <unsigned int N>
struct byte_t {
    bool bits[N];
    byte_t() {
        for (int n = N; n > 0; n--)
            bits[n] = false;
        cout << "Created " << N << "-bit byte: " << str() << endl;
    }
    string dstr() {
        ostringstream ss;
        for (int n = N; n > 0; n--)
            if (bits[n] == true) ss << '1';
            else                 ss << '0';
        return ss.str();
    }
    string str() {
        ostringstream ss;
        for (int n = N; n > 0; n--)
            ss << bits[n];
        return ss.str();
    }
};

int main(int argc,char** argv) {
    byte_t<8> my_byte;
    cout << my_byte.str() << endl;
    cout << my_byte.str() << endl;
    cout << my_byte.dstr() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now here is the expected outcome, and what comes out on IDEOne (see http://ideone.com/JL0m4R):

```
Created 8-bit byte: 00000000
00000000
00000000
00000000
```

Strangely enough on my mac (10.8.4) after compiling with

```
g++ -o byte byte.cc
```

this is the output I get:

```
Created 8-bit byte: 00000000
00000000
240000000
10000000
```

I can't explain this, but I guess there must be some very simple explanation.

Thanks!

Proof:

[image]

Comment: hint: output the array indices you are writing to

Comment: Also, why `int n = N`? Consider when `N` holds a value larger than `int` can hold. Just use an unsigned type (to match your template argument), and count from 0 like 99% of other loops. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Stupid mistake. Yes uint is better, I agree.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are writing to, and reading from, outside the bounds of the array, and so have *undefined behavior*.

Remember, an array of size `N` have indexes from `0` to `N - 1`.